# Firefox keeps implementing task in Task Scheduler

Tags: firefox, scheduled-tasks

There is a task in my Task Scheduler added by Firefox called "Firefox Default Browser Agent". Every 10 minutes it takes focus away from what ever I'm doing and opens a cmd for about 0.01 seconds. It is driving me nuts. When I try to disable it, the next day it is re-enabled. If I try and delete it, the next day, it is back.

If I try to change the settings of the event to only trigger once a day, the next day, it's back to doing it every 10 minutes. Is this a just delete and don't use Firefox thing or is there a way to fix this issue?

---

**Update**: It's been about a week and I am still having this issue. I've tried [@harrymc solution below](https://superuser.com/a/1821590/167207), but that didn't seem to fix it. I've even tried compleatly uninstalling Firefox and it is still happening. I've tried deleting it via the terminal as admin (`schtasks /delete /tn "Firefox Default Browser Agent 72226B67F32032C0"`). That is also not working. I've tried disabling it. I've tried changing different parts of the task to maybe make it start in the year 2099.

Everything I do to it, it just keeps resetting like groundhogs day.

Comment: Sounds to me like a bug. I'd complain to Mozilla and file a bug report. In the meanwhile, I'd remove firefox and install an older version until they fix the issue.

Comment: @LPChip This doesn’t happen to me on any of numerous devices, and I’m sure if it was a common problems someone would already have kicked off about it. So the fact this task is running in the foreground must be due to some weird issue on the OP’s system.

Comment: It has never happened on any of my other devices either. I just got a new computer and it is happening on this one. I don't know why. As for others "kicking off" about it, they have. There are quite a few posts out there about people talking about this issue. They just never gave any solutions that worked for me.

Comment: Is this a work computer or personal? You note you just "got" it, so perhaps there is some manufacturer bloatware insisting on a Firefox install? I recommend refreshing Windows to get a default install, free of branded bloat/garbage.

Answer (score 23):

Mozilla says this about the
[Default Browser Agent](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/toolkit/mozapps/defaultagent/default-browser-agent/) :

> The Default Browser Agent is a Windows-only scheduled task which runs in the background to collect and submit data about the browser that the user has set as their OS default (that is, the browser that will be invoked by the operating system to open web links that the user clicks on in other programs). Its purpose is to help Mozilla understand user’s default browser choices and, in the future, to engage with users at a time when they may not be actively running Firefox.

The Default Browser Agent is not critical and may be disabled
without any problem to Firefox.

You can disable this agent via Firefox's *Advanced Preferences* page that you open by typing `about:config` in Firefox's address bar. After going to that page, click "Accept the Risk and Continue", then type the following into that page's search field:

`default-browser-agent.enabled`

When that entry is displayed with the value of "true", double-click
the entry to toggle it to "false".

Comment: Okay. I've done it. I'll let y'all know tomorrow if it worked (assuming I remember).

Comment: I find it unacceptable, there should be a more obvious option to opt-out of this "study".

Comment: @SalmanA you can easily opt out of all studies from Settings - Privacy.

Comment: In addition to being used for studying user choices, this task has also been used to help identify cases where the default browser is changed maliciously.

Comment: @barbecue you mean by Microsoft, who go out of their way to make it difficult to switch the default browser, and then at times feel like you've made the wrong choice and helpfully switch you back to Edge?

Comment: @darren That's a great example.

Comment: It's been a few days now and this is still happening. See original question for more info.

Comment: From your description it seems like the task is repeatedly being re-created. I've in Task Scheduler exported the task's description to XML and posted it on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/XUSC0h6A). Please do the same with yours, so we can compare the differences. You can also try to change the task's trigger and then change the permissions on it so it becomes untouchable (unless by a system-permission task).

Comment: Here is the XML: https://pastebin.com/ujwgVjaU

Comment: Your task does not seem at all like mine - doesn't even look like it's really from Firefox. I'm afraid your computer is infected, so I suggest to run deep antivirus scans by at least Defender and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download).

Comment: ... Afterward, ensure to delete `C:\Users\postm\AppData\Roaming\jsgtvwe`. In case of difficulties, reboot in Safe mode to delete it.