# Windows 10 CMD Command Prompt opens and closes for split second. Possible Malware?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, malware, windows-task-scheduler

Every now and then I get a random command window open and closes for a split second. I can't see what it is. But I'm assuming it is a scheduled thing. I just want to be safe. From the get scheduled task and sorting it by time. These are the last things run in the past 10 minutes of when I noticed the cmd open. Do any of these things look like a culprit?

I opened up powershell (admin) and typed in this command:

```
Get-ScheduledTask |  Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Sort LastRunTime -Descending | Select TaskName, TaskPath, LastRunTime | ogv
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1821573/firefox-keeps-implementing-task-in-task-scheduler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox keeps implementing task in Task Scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/1821573/firefox-keeps-implementing-task-in-task-scheduler)

Answer (score 1):

A recent post about the exact same thing told me this is the Firefox Default Browser Agent Task.

Firefox has an option in their software that you can disable to stop the scheduled task.

See also: [Firefox Keeps implementing task in Task Scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/1821573/firefox-keeps-implementing-task-in-task-scheduler)

> You can disable this agent via Firefox's Advanced Preferences page that you open by typing about:config in Firefox's address bar. After going to that page, click "Accept the Risk and Continue", then type the following into that page's search field:

> default-browser-agent.enabled

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the list rings the bell for me, so here is one method of
perhaps catching this CMD:

- Download and unpack
  [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)
- Run it and create the following filters (Remove the extra ones) :

  - Process Name is cmd.exe
  - Operation is Load Image

    [image]
- Minimize it and let it run
- When you see the CMD popping up, unminimize and doucle-click
  the Load Image item for `cmd.exe`
- Examine the Process tab - the Command Line entry may tell you more
  about the reason this CMD was called.

Comment: Really? Even after you posted an answer about this yesterday?

Comment: @LPChip: This post says "Every now and then", while the other post says "Every 10 minutes". More information is needed for a definitive conclusion, which is the point in my answer.

Comment: While I can agree with that assessment, the fact that they also looked up the tasks for the past 10 minutes, and this is a hot issue, makes it almost a perfect match.